# How to create a database diagrams in visual studio code?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-code, rdbms, diagram

I am trying Visual studio code to code the database but I cannot create the database diagram. Is there a way I can create it just like in SSMS.
Thank you.

[image: VS Code window]

Comment: Check [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaishuu0123.vscode-erd-preview) extension out.

Comment: there is also SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox which helps managing SQLite/SQL with EF a lot and also can create a diagram

Answer (score 14):

1. Install the ERD Editor extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dineug.vuerd-vscode
2. Create a file with the extension `.vuerd.json`, e.g. `somedb.vuerd.json`
3. Click the Open ERD Editor icon at the top right:

[image]

Comment: It is really awesome. Apart from supporting multiple databases and giving export options it also generates entity types.